# Relay not getting triggered from NodeMCU high

Tags: relay, nodemcu

Please bear with me since am a noob in electronics. I made a relay module based on internet DIY [tutorials](https://images.app.goo.gl/WEwRyWRU68xg8TjK6).[image: DIY Tutorial] It turns on when I provide 5V from adapter to both +5V and signal but when I supply high of NodeMCU to signal pin it doesn't work. Any suggestions what is wrong with module I created?

Also want to check if this sketch is using optocoupler correctly. I have no clue :(

Relay used https://sharvielectronics.com/product/spdt-5v-30a-relay-pcb-mount/

Comment: The nodeMCU looks like a 3.3V device rather then 5V. 3.3V is probably too low for both the optocoupler LED and the green LED in series. You can try bridging the green LED which should result in roughly 5mA trough the opto LED.

Comment: Please show your circuit. I don’t find any datasheet for it but coil needs in the order of 400 mW. How do you supply it?

Comment: @varun, if you edit the question there is a circuit schematic tool that you can use to draw an example circuit

Comment: you can use a transistor (npn or nchan) to fix this. 5v- signal via 20k resistor. signal to tranny's drain/collector, tranny's source/emitter to gnd. Tranny's gate/base to nodeMCU pin. Note: the logic will be inverted HI/LO.

Comment: @winny  - added the schematic diagram

Comment: @VoltageSpike - added the schematic diagram

Comment: @dandavis - Can you please share a diagram please, as I said am pretty noob with electronics terminology

Comment: @Unimportant - by bridge you mean remove?

Comment: Where is Vcc coming from? Why the optocoupler?

Comment: Bridge as in replacing with a piece of wire...

Comment: @winny - Vcc and ground from 5v mobile charger

Comment: @winny - my understanding of using optocouplor is to avoid any damage to microcontroller (nodemcu in my case)

Comment: Is it capable of pulling the relay by itself? Please elaborate on damage to microcontroller. My proposal is to reduce your circuit to a bog standard NFET with low Vgsth straight from your MCU to drive your relay with your free wheeling diode kept as you have drawn it.

Comment: @winny yes with Vcc and `input` from the mobile adapter turns on the relay.. but if i provide `input` from nodemcu(3.3v) and Vcc from adapter relay doesnt  work.  Regarding Damage to microcontroller- i read that without octocoupler nodemcu can burn in case of any mishappen with relay. Can you please share diagram of your suggestion I dont understand any electronic jargons yet :(

Comment: @Unimportant - can i directly connect them with a wire or have to remove led first? As you must have know by now am not much into these soldering and circuit things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is 3.3V output from nodemcu. Added a level shifter and also removed with green LED as suggested by @Unimportant

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you for adding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using an optocoupler due to "avoid any damage to microcontroller" is questionable. I see where you are coming from, but better start with something working and adding protections if needed (you won't).

This is the most bog standard setup for triggering a relay from an MCU:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fovUje.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 may be over the top, but sometimes it's a cheap way to get around with too low capacitance for non critical things like your relay while making sure you won't brown-out your MCU.

Comment: I dont have mosfet available will bc547b or 2n2222A work?  Or if with some minor alterations my current circuit can work? Had created 2 of them dont want to redo everything :(

Comment: Sure, ditch the optocoupler, calculate your base resistor to be within the limit of how much the MCU can source and that you are saturating it for your relay coil consumption.

Comment: Tried that even that didnt work for me with nodemcu... Works with 5v :(

Comment: Ditch the MCU. Apply 5 V to the base resistor. Does it pull the relay?

Comment: Tried these nothing works with nodemcu :https://youtu.be/HXiL8p_sDZ8
drive.google.com/file/d/127OrtJif8SwfH3pJHJS8Kd-bYoOSEjfe/view

Comment: Again, minimize your problem. Remove the MCU and apply 5 V directly to your base resistor. Does it pull the relay?

Comment: yes it does without MCU with original structure too... Resolved the issue.. Adding the answer